# Android Customised Listviewadapterdialog hides softinputkeyboard

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, keyboard

The Scenario I am Facing is given below

> On-focus of my dialog edittext I want keyboard to appear above the
>   dialog.

[image]

I go through so many answers in SO. but not working

> code in adapter class edittext onfocus

```
 edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    public void onFocusChange (View v,boolean hasFocus){
        edittext.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            }
        });
```

> Listview

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(promptsView);
            builder.setTitle(" Please select size");

            listView = (ListView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.listt);
            dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, R.layout.size_info,
                    sizePojoList, active);
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
            listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Comment: can you post some code which you have tried.

Comment: post some code implementation or your layout

Comment: Is keyvoar is already open before dialog open ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana No, only onfocus keyboard open

Comment: @NovoLucas Check the edited question

Comment: @RonakThakkar Check the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>